# How to use MyLocation-Button at Google Map API V2

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

I want to make that when click in MyLocation-Button show a Toast.
I try this code:

```
public void setMyLocationLayerEnabled(View v) {
    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Example de Message for Android", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    toast.show();
}
```

But no work. I hope somebody of you can help me!

Comment: Try out with `getActivity()` besides `getApplicationContext()`.

Comment: `But no work.` ? please explain more what happen when clicking on button and also use logs to simulate button click event

Comment: I use log and my problem is that when I button click event no show the logs. In conclusion no acces this set setMyLocationLayerEnabled. Where do I have to put setMyLocationLayerEnabled?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
map.setOnMyLocationButtonClickListener(new OnMyLocationButtonClickListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onMyLocationButtonClick() {
                    Toast.makeText(
                            getActivity(),
                            "Example de Message for Android",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return true;
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 3):

To get the current location after clicking MyLocationButton, then use

```
`googleMap.getMyLocation();  //Deprecated,  So use `googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true); //Which allows to deal with current location`
```

inside setOnMyLocationButtonClickListener.

Reference link: https://www.androidtutorialpoint.com/intermediate/android-map-app-showing-current-location-android/

Hope it helps ! And thanks to Cabezas.

Comment: getMyLocation() is now deprecated. Is there any other method which we can use to get location?

Comment: @idrisjafer, edited the answer, please have a look, hope it helps. Have a great day